# Can tkinter be used for languages without an upper/lower case distinction?

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

It is an error to give a tkinter widget a name which begins with an upper case character as in:

```
b = ttk.Button(self, name='OK')
```

What happens in languages which do not have a distinction between upper and lower case such as logogrammatical languages? Presumably tkinter flags the upper case as an error because it would create some kind of internal problem.

If this has been resolved for non Latin languages there would be no point in retaining the error for Latin languages. If it has not been resolved then tkinter has a bug when non Latin languages are used.

My fear is that choosing tkinter, tk, and ttl will mean that my program may not work in any language other than those which use a Roman alphabet.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably I didn't understand because it seems like you're implying that i.e. Windows in Chinese cannot deal with an uppercase initial in a widget... Seems like too strange a limitation for a decent OS... Or could you show an example of an actual situation when this happens?

Comment: Sadly, I only speak English so I cannot give any examples. As far as I am aware the notion of upper and lower case is completely alien to Chinese.  tkinter does predate the widespread introduction of Unicode as did Python <3.

Comment: FWIW, Tkinter is based on tcl/tk, and in tcl/tk, all strings are unicode (and have been since 1999). The issue with widget names is relatively moot -- there's almost no reason to ever specify a widget name). The workaround is simple - add a lowercase letter as a prefix and then use whatever characters you want.

Comment: @Brian Oakley. So far, I'm naming every widget I can as I'm finding that it enables cleaner code. Otherwise, if you want to unittest widget W in a class then widget W has  to have a separate Python identifier. Also, the Python identifier will identify the widget by its tkinter path which would include the whole structure if it is part of a compound widget. Thus every unittest of a widget will also be a test of the hierarchy to which it belongs. Using the name is the only way I know to get around this problem. I'll welcome information on alternatives.

Comment: @Brian Oakley. p.s. Your workaround will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter uses tcl/tk as the underlying technology to render widgets. In Tcl/tk, all strings are unicode strings. When determining whether a character is uppercase or lowercase it looks at the unicode attributes of those characters. If the unicode standard says a character is lowercase, that character is allowed as the first character of a widget name.

Comment: ...and if it's uppercase?

Comment: @Roberto: The first character of the name must be lowercase. That's the rule. If unicode says it's not lowercase you'll get an exception. Tkinter just uses the information from the unicode standard.

Comment: Your answer implies that the name, 'MyButton', would become acceptable if the unicode specification were to be changed. It's not likely but take it as a thought experiment. If that situation would not present any problem to either tkinter or tk then what is the purpose of testing for a leading uppercase? It wouldn't be doing anything useful. I wonder if this is a pointless remnant of an ancient ASCII convention.

Comment: @lemi57ssss: The purpose of checking for a leading lowercase character goes back to Tkinter's heritage -- in the option database (the way you could define "styles" in X11) a lowercase first letter meant a widget instance, an uppercase meant a widget class. If a widget began with an uppercase it would be impossible to distinguish between the two, so the rule was put in place. The tcl maintainers put a very high premium on backwards compatibility, and considering the workaround (and the need for the workaround) is so small, this will likely not ever change.

Comment: If anyone can show me how to do test drive the development of tkinter with or without widget names I would be exceedingly grateful. Until then I'm wading through this swamp all on my own and naming widgets has become an important technique.